# Can you apply noatime on ext3 partitions at realtime?

Tags: mount, filesystem, performance, ext3

An application accesses a disk directory containing about 3 million files (including directories).

I would like to apply the `noatime` option for that filesystem and I would like to know whether I can do that while applications are running and accessing that filesystem.

The command I'd apply would look like this:

```bsh
mount -o remount,noatime /
```

Any experience with that? I run one single application using the file system, and it is a 100% Java application (1 JVM running).

Ubuntu Version: 9.10 (Karmic)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command you proposed while the system is running, for security reasons I would do it during the night or when the application is not in use.
The command `mount` return, among other lines, somthing like this

```
/dev/sda5 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro,data=writeback)
```

then if you issue the command you proposed

```
mount -o remount,noatime /
```

the output of the command `mount` looks like this

```
/dev/sda5 on / type ext4 (rw,noatime,errors=remount-ro,data=writeback)
```

showing that the option was added correctly.
Hope I helped you!